# Negative margin is not allowing in html is there any other solution to do?

Tags: html, css, email

**I know that negative margin and position properties won't support in email but can anyone suggest me how to do this with out using negative margin and position property?**

**code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Rejected Mailer</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="middle" style="width:50%;margin:0 auto; background:#f4f4f4;">
        <div class="center_block" style="background:#fff;padding: 2%;height:auto;width:80%;margin:-8% auto; ox-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); word-wrap: break-word;">
            <h5>Dear Supplier,</h5>
            <p>Your product has been rejected. Because of the following reasons:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Product image quality should be high.</li>
                    <li>Make sure your product price should match with whole sale market price less than all retailer price.</li>
                    <li>Product description should match with product.</li>
                    <li>Should not copy the description of your product from any other ecommerce website.</li>
                    <li>Unit should match with product.</li>
                    <li> Before adding product, choose proper category of the product you are going to be add.</li>
                </ul>
                <h5>Your Product Details:</h5>
                <ul class="nobullets">
                    <li>Product Name: Rice Flour</li>
                    <li>Product Description: XXXXXXXXXX</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer" style="background:#000;padding: 1%;height:auto;width:80%;margin: 8% auto;color:#fff;">
                <p class="text-center">&copy ABC</p>
            </div>
    </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[image: I want output like this]
[image: But i am getting output like this]

Comment: `but can anyone suggest me how to do this` , do what exactly ?

Comment: _"can anyone suggest me how to do this"_ - do _what_? You have shown us _unformatted_ HTML code - no inline styles, only a few classes we know nothing about. So if you want _that_ in an email, it’s copy&paste, done. Otherwise, you need to first of all explain what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. I don't know where you thought of using the negative margins ? Maybe when centering the div ? Anyway, look at the code below. It replicates your pictures. Let me know if this is what you are looking for

```html
 <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Rejected Mailer</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="middle" style="width:50%;margin:0 auto; background:#f4f4f4;">
        <div class="center_block" style="background:#fff;padding: 2%;height:auto;width:80%;margin:-8% auto; nox-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); word-wrap: break-word; box-sizing:border-box">
            <h5>Dear Supplier,</h5>
            <p>Your product has been rejected. Because of the following reasons:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Product image quality should be high.</li>
                    <li>Make sure your product price should match with whole sale market price less than all retailer price.</li>
                    <li>Product description should match with product.</li>
                    <li>Should not copy the description of your product from any other ecommerce website.</li>
                    <li>Unit should match with product.</li>
                    <li> Before adding product, choose proper category of the product you are going to be add.</li>
                </ul>
                <h5>Your Product Details:</h5>
                <ul class="nobullets">
                    <li>Product Name: Rice Flour</li>
                    <li>Product Description: XXXXXXXXXX</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer" style="background:#000;padding: 1%;height:auto;width:80%;margin: 8% auto;color:#fff;box-sizing:border-box">
                <p class="text-center">&copy ABC</p>
            </div>
    </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you for your patience can you please check my code i have edited just now @Mihai T

Comment: @MaruthiPrasad changed answer with your code. Added `box-sizing:border-box` so the padding stay inside the element, not expand outside the element

Comment: In localhost it is supporting but in mail it's not working

Comment: @MaruthiPrasad well then you should research a little bit what is working and what not inside e-mails. Check here > https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/ . you can use `table` layout for your email. That is supported by every provider out there